# Is memory_order_acquire really sufficient for locking a spinlock?

Tags: c++, atomic

According to Antony Williams' book *C++ Concurrency in Action* a spinlock can be implemented as follows:

```
class spinlock_mutex {
  std::atomic_flag flag;

public:
  spinlock_mutex() : flag(ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT) {}

  void lock() {
    while (flag.test_and_set(std::memory_order_acquire)) ;
  }

  void unlock() {
   flag.clear(std::memory_order_release);
  }
};
```

If I understand correctly, the `memory_order_acquire` tag ensures visibility of the most recent store operation that used the `memory_order_release` tag. ("A release operation *synchronizes-with* an acquire operation.")

Since `test_and_set` is also a store operation I would expect that a `memory_order_acq_rel` tag is required inside the `lock()` method in order to ensure visibility of the locked state in other threads that attempt to lock the mutex.

Why is `memory_order_acquire` sufficient?

Comment: acquire is only ever enough if the only other thread uses release, AFAIR

Comment: @sehe iow, you agree that ack_rel is needed in the lock method..?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The acquire and release are related not to this atomic variable, but to the rest of variables read/written in each one of the threads.

To make it more obvious, without the release in `unlock()` and the acquire in the `lock()` the flag would still be visible. The problem is that a write to a variable protected by the spin lock may be pushed *after* the lock is released, introducing a race condition. In the same way a read of that variable inside the lock might be moved to before the `lock()`

Comment: Would the flag modification also be visible when using relaxed atomics? (Assuming, for the sake of argument, that we don't care about the other variables.)

Comment: "The acquire and release are related not to this atomic variable" doesn't sound right. Quite _obviously_ it [is related](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_flag/test_and_set). I appreciate the other point you're making. It may be relevant, but I can't agree with such a bold statement.

Comment: @sehe: Let's say that they don't affect how the read/writes to this variable happen. The synchronizes-with means that if a different thread sees the updated value then (in this case with release/acquire) it will also see any writes before the update to the lock. But it does not affect how and when the value of this particular variable is visible in the other thread

Comment: @StackedCrooked: Yes, in relaxed mode the flag will be visible, but it won't *synchronize*, the compiler will be able to move operations that are performed inside the spinlock outside of the critical region, and it will really not *lock* or *unlock* anything.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas does that mean that writes to the atomic_flag bypass the cache entirely? (is this unique to atomic_flag, or does this hold for all atomic variables?)

Comment: @StackedCrooked Read-Modify-Write operations are special. Per 29.3/12 "Atomic read-modify-write operations shall always read the last value (in the modification order) written before the write associated with the read-modify-write operation." The memory ordering you select for such an R-M-W op only affects how it is ordered with reads/writes to other memory locations and non R-M-W ops to the same atomic. As far as the `atomic_flag` itself is concerned, the `test_and_set` and `clear` could both be relaxed and provide mutual exclusion - but it wouldn't order accesses to other memory locations.